Remove background from line art
I have line art images (scans of prints from an engraving), and I want to be able to edit the images to remove the background art while leaving the foreground. I have about 600 images that I want to edit.
Example Image:

What is the fastest way to remove the background from these types of images?
Constraints:

keep the original image resolution and quality
keep the results from labour intensive intermediate steps (for re-editing later if needed)
using image editing tools on windows
preferably using free tools

willing to pay about 200$ for a tool if it is significantly faster than the manual process described below with the same quality of results




My current solution is to:

manually paint a mask (on a separate layer) that exactly covers each object that I want to keep in the final image
then use the magic want tool to select the mask
invert the selection to select only the background
delete the background from the original image
hide the masking layers

Here is an example original image and the result from the masking procedure.
downsized original image: (source: KU Leuven - Libraries Special Collections https://resolver.libis.be/IE6804696/representation image 113 )

intermediate masked image:

final edited image:


That's quite an opinionated "foreground"... I would expect most "background removal" would leave all of the people while removing the walls and perhaps the floor. Are all of your background removals this stylistic? What criteria determines what should be kept?

The tool you're looking for is an intern... You won't find an automated tool for this job. "Background removal"doesn't mean what you're asking for here.

The quickest way is probably with Adobe Photoshop, but it isn't free.  It has a fairly nice Object Selection tool. Basically, it can automatically see individual human objects in an image, and you can just click on them to make a selection. Once you have made a selection, you could apply it as a layer mask.
However, it's not really designed for these kind of images, rather for actual photographs.
I tested this, and it still works, but the results are far from perfect, and the layer mask would need to be edited manually to fix the imperfections. Although this would be a great starting point for an edit, this could be extremely time consuming given the number of images you have.
Here's an example showing what the Object Selection tool can do with the image you linked to. As you can see, there are several missing pieces which would need to be put back manually.


Clipping 600 images sounds massive. But it's nothing when compared to what's done by the makers of the originals. The modern easy life in western countries has made us so lazy that I guess there's not many GDSE members who envy your job.
The situation is different in many developing countries like India. There are so many talented and diligent people packed in every metropolis that any job would be welcome, even this. Unfortunately it still costs money, although only a fraction of the bill which would be written by a New York graphics work company. Check your outsourcing options!
If you want to do this by yourself you really must draw the clipping borders manually. Painting them (like you already have done) is one way, but doing it consistently and fast needs well trained hands and eyes and, of course, good equipment. Painting 600 of these with a mouse sounds insane.
Generally available commercial artificial intelligence tools (in Photoshop plus some others) are not up to the task, as it's been already shown in another answer. I'm afraid clever enough software will not be available soon, because military and entertainment industries sink most programmers who are capable enough to utilize AI technologies based on new math inventions.
I suggest a variation of your manual method. It needs only Inkscape which is freeware. It may easily take a week to make the pen tool and editing nodes and curves so familiar that you really get anything done fast enough. How to get the skills? Work tutorials and practice!!
At first import and lock the bitmap image. Then draw outlines of the shapes with one color (green) and use another color (red) to draw the edges of the holes.

As you see, the green (closed) paths overlap. That's no harm because you will make later an union.
It's essential to use only exactly the same 2 colors. Fortunately you can continue automatically with the same color as you used in your last shape if it's selected in the tool preferences.
Save your work before making combinations. It's a good idea to keep the colors in separate layers.
Select all green shapes and make a path union. Use Edit > Select same stroke color. Unite then the red shapes and subtract the red one from the green. Use the result as your clipping path (Object > Clip > Set).
The clipping can be released if needed. But be sure that you have available also all originally drawn green and red paths.

Recent Inkscape has got quite well working Shape Builder. Using it to combine outlines and hole edges instead of making Boolean unions and differences is a real option. Using the shape builder creates easily numerous unnecessary nodes to paths which make later edits slow. But there's no need to draw closed paths. Edges can well be open paths as long as they together define closed areas. That's a substantial advantage. Besides Inkscape generally allows you to delete unnecessary nodes without changing the curve too much.You can delete unnecessary nodes manually one by one with the node tool or you can apply Path > Simplify. Applying it once removes generally only the unnecessary nodes if they exist.
